# Espresso - TextView contains String

Tags: android, android-espresso

Quite simply, how do I say if a given `TextView` contains a specific string in `Espresso`.

The equivalent of: `myStrings.contains("Subby");`

Answer (score 122):

You can use the Hamcrest library. It has a method containsString.
I believe it is in the Espresso library.

You can static import it in your class:

```
import static org.hamcrest.core.StringContains.containsString;
```

Use containsString in your method on a TextView:

```
textView.check(matches(withText(containsString("Test"))));
```

Comment: This is the only legitimate answer to the original question.

Comment: you mean to say it validates if textview contain any string

Comment: Yes, that is what you can check with containsString. @AhmadArslan

Answer (score 33):

Use `withText`

```
onView(...).check(matches(withText("Subby")));

onView(withId(R.id.textView)).check(matches(withText("Subby")));
```

Comment: Use `withText(startsWith("Subby"))` to match a TextView which starts with your desired text. (Same goes for `withText(endsWith(...))`

Answer (score 27):

Use `withSubstring(substring)`, it is same as `withText(containsString(substring))` but more concise